# How To Set My SSL Credential To ElasticSearch In Docker-Compose File

Tags: elasticsearch, ssl, docker-compose

I am a Docker and Es config rookie, I want to configure SSL credential to ElasticSearch in my Docker-Compose file.

This is the SSL from Tencent Cloud, Which credential I could choise? It make me feeling very confused

[image]

And this is reference [link](https://raphaeldelio.medium.com/how-to-start-a-elasticsearch-docker-container-with-ssl-tls-encryption-c3cf7e00c646) I learn how to configure SSL.

When I visit the ES web , It will prompt me to enter the password. I can login successfully by password and see the relevant information of ES.

But the web·page  display using an unsafe certificate that 'Invalid certificate' and when I try to use the SpringBoot link, there will be a link error like this .

[image: Error Stack Message]

And there are my Docker-Compose config

`instances.yml` :

```
instances:
  - name: es01
    dns:
      - es01 
      - localhost
    ip:
      - MyIp

  - name: es02
    dns:
      - es02
      - localhost
    ip:
      - MyIp
  - name: es03
    dns:
      - es03
      - localhost
    ip:
      - MyIp
```

`.env`:

```
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=es 
CERTS_DIR=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certificates 
ELASTIC_PASSWORD=PleaseChangeMe
```

`create-certs.yml`:

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  create_certs:
    container_name: create_certs
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.14.1
    command: >
      bash -c '
        if [[ ! -f /certs/bundle.zip ]]; then
          bin/elasticsearch-certutil cert --silent --pem --in config/certificates/instances.yml -out /certs/bundle.zip;
          unzip /certs/bundle.zip -d /certs; 
        fi;
        chown -R 1000:0 /certs
      '
    user: "0"
    working_dir: /usr/share/elasticsearch
    volumes: ['certs:/certs', '.:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certificates']
volumes: {"certs"}
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  es01:
    container_name: es01
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.14.1
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es02,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=$ELASTIC_PASSWORD 
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - xpack.license.self_generated.type=trial 
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.key=$CERTS_DIR/es01/es01.key
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities=$CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate=$CERTS_DIR/es01/es01.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode=certificate 
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities=$CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate=$CERTS_DIR/es01/es01.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.key=$CERTS_DIR/es01/es01.key
    volumes: ['data01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data', 'certs:$CERTS_DIR']
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    healthcheck:
      test: curl --cacert $CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt -s https://localhost:9200 >/dev/null; if [[ $$? == 52 ]]; then echo 0; else echo 1; fi
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
  es02:
    container_name: es02
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.14.1
    environment:
      - node.name=es02
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es02,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=$ELASTIC_PASSWORD
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - xpack.license.self_generated.type=trial
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.key=$CERTS_DIR/es02/es02.key
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities=$CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate=$CERTS_DIR/es02/es02.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode=certificate 
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities=$CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate=$CERTS_DIR/es02/es02.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.key=$CERTS_DIR/es02/es02.key
    volumes: ['data02:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data', 'certs:$CERTS_DIR']
  es03:
    container_name: es03
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.14.1
    environment:
      - node.name=es03
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es02,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=$ELASTIC_PASSWORD
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - xpack.license.self_generated.type=trial
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.key=$CERTS_DIR/es03/es03.key
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities=$CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate=$CERTS_DIR/es03/es03.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode=certificate 
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities=$CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate=$CERTS_DIR/es03/es03.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.key=$CERTS_DIR/es03/es03.key
    volumes: ['data03:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data', 'certs:$CERTS_DIR']

  wait_until_ready:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.14.1
    command: /usr/bin/true
    depends_on: {"es01": {"condition": "service_healthy"}}
volumes: {"data01", "data02","data03", "certs"}
```

And there are my some questions:

1. How do I configure my SSL certificate to my ES. If I can't configure it, what kind of way I should choose to add SSL to my ES, is there a reference link?
2. And If I cant configure my SSL to ES , how should I configure the website so that it will not prompt that it is unsafe, and it can be successfully linking in SpringBoot
3. **[Finish,Run `docker-compose -f create-certs.yml run --rm create_certs` After configuration of `instances.yml`]**~~ When I use `Docker-compose up`, ES03 cannot be initialized and `Docker logs` is
   At the same time, ES01 will report an error prompt to find ES03. How can I modify the configuration to make ES03 effective ~~
4. When I successfully configure SSL in ES, how should my Kibana configure

Thank you very much for your help. If you have any suggestions or opinions, welcome to speak !!!